# Include Bootstrap CSS in <head> with Wicket

Tags: html, css, wicket

I'm using Wicket to create the HTML body of an email. I like to use Bootstrap for styling but since link tags are ignored in emails... Is there a (nice) way in Wicket to import the Bootstrap CSS into a style tag in the header?

I already searched the internet for a solution but found nothing even close to my problem. Which is strange since CSS inlining should be a common technique to reduce roundtrips in page loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wicket has `CssHeaderItem.forString()` that will render `<style>...</style>`. So you just need to read `bootstrap.css` and use it. You can use `Class#getResourceAsStream()`, commons-io, Wicket's `PackageResource`, ... It depends where `bootstrap.css` is located in your application.

Comment: Thanks... This is the correct answer to my question... Unfortunately it is not the answer I needed. As I found out there are email clients that even ignore the style tag. So styles have to be inlined... Fortunately ZURB Foundation provides an email css library and an inlining tool... https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner-v2.html